# What is involved in adding ZFS cache stats to orca?

Tags: performance, solaris, performance-monitoring, solaris-10, system-monitoring

I am interested in looking to add ZFS cache stats into existing orca performance monitoring that we have.

Particularly, I am interested in the output of echo ::memstat | mdb -k

Am still in the early stages of studying the configuration for orca and would appreciate some guidance.

I wonder if it would mean adding columns into the existing orcallator output.

Comment: Yes, it would. I wouldn't bother, though.